# How fix a problem when I change the expression of `x_new` inside the following function `phix`?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to change the expression of `x_new` inside the following function `phix` defined as follows.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The code for this function is as follows.

```
def phix(x, N):
  lam=np.floor(N**(1/3))
  x_new=0
  for i in range(0, int(lam)):
   if (i+1)*N**(-1/3)>x>i*N**(-1/3):
    x_new=x_new+(2*i+1)/(2*N**(1/3))
  return x_new
```

```
N=1000
x=0.57
phix(x, N)
```

> 0.55

If I replace `x_new` by `phix(x,N)` directly, there will be a problem, because the function I define here can only work on one `x`, not `N` many `x`. How to fix it?

Comment: The mathematical expression for `x_new` is totally confusing... looking at your implemented function, you are just using one summand, because the intervals you are checking are disjoined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, you could just use `np.vectorize`, you may better step back and re-think what actually happens when working with numpy arrays. This will help you to write more efficient/faster code, so you do not start blaming python for being slow :-).

In the original function, you want to replace the following line

```py
x_new = N**(-1/3)*np.floor(N**(1/3)*x)
```

where `N` is an integer and `x` is an array of floats.
Assuming that `x` is one dimensional, this is equivalent to

```py
# allocate memory for new array
x_new = np.empty_like(x)
# calculate the spacing
step = N**(-1/3)
# loop though elements in x
for i in range(len(x)):
    # access x at position i
    x_i = x[i]
    # use floor division to get the bin index
    bin_idx = x_i // step
    # set the new value at position i in x_new
    x_new[i] = bin_idx * step
```

Such a loop in python would be very slow, so numpy implements a shortcut which looks like working with a single position. Let us now split the one liner a bit, to separate the steps still using fast numpy loops under the hood.

```py
step = N**(-1/3)
bin_idx = x // step
x_new = step * bin_idx
```

What you want are the middle points of those bins, which you can easily calculate now

```py
step = N**(-1/3)
bin_idx = x // step
x_new = step * (2*bin_idx + 1)/2
```

You see, that there was no need to introduce a function which loops on the bin spacing when understanding the original idea which uses the floor division to bin the data.

The following is beyond the question, but still worth to point out.
The next lines in your code could also improve a bit

```py
x_val = np.array(list(Counter(x_new).keys()))
x_freq = np.array(list(Counter(x_new).values()))
```

What the counter does is basically summing how many values fall into the bin. Even though it is not extremely expensive, you should not do that twice, but instead re-use the instance `counter = Counter(x_new)`. However, what you are doing here is building a histogram. Since you already computed the bin values `x_new`, you can use `x_val, x_freq = np.unique(x_new, return_counts=True)` to get the frequencies.

Please note that the way you want to re-label `x_new` will not change the result of your function. So there is not really a benefit in doing it unless you implement a non-equal spacing for the bins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `N` is always a constant, you can use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
def adapW1_eot(x, y, N: int):
    x_new = np.vectorize(phix)(x, N)
    ...
```

Then `x_new` will be a NumPy array.